# Would it be better to interrupt() an idle thread rather than wait()/notify()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `Manager` that manages a couple of `FileSystems` (my own abstraction). It's possible that one of these `FileSystems` receives no data for awhile, so I'd like to idle it. Whenever data is finally received by the `Manager`, it should awaken the respective idle `FileSystem`. Right now I'm using `wait()` and `notify()` and I get the results I want.

However, the whole point of idling a `FileSystem` was to consume less resources. I was wondering if it may be better to just `interrupt()` the `Thread` then create a new one when it's time to activate a `FileSystem` (could take ten minutes or more for new data to come in)? Wouldn't waiting still hog resources?

Here's the setup of my `Runnable`.

```
public class FileSystem implements Runnable
{
    public FileSystem()
    {
        // do stuff
        startTimer()
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    //public void startTimer()
    //{
    //    new Thread(new Runnable()
    //    {
    //        @Override
    //        public void run()
    //        {
    //            // do something
    //        }
    //    }).start();
    //}

    // other methods
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the `FileSystem` is not actually idle at the instant when the interrupt is delivered?

Comment: It finishes what it's doing then idles. I have a wrapper method ensuring interruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If read operation create lot of resources and happens very frequently then better for waiting for file. But if read thread is light and sits idle a lot, then better create new thread.

Comment: I ended up interrupting the `Thread` then creating a new `Thread` when needed. There were no operations done unless the `Thread` was needed. Using a `Runnable` meant any data I had was still in memory so startup times were negligible. I managed to reduce CPU Usage by ~10-35% using interrupts and still have everything working as it should. Thank you!